# How do I rewrite this Linq query to avoid using FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Quotes table, which has an associated Revisions table. A basic business rule is that a quote must have at least one revision, but may have many. I have a query that starts like this...

```
var revisions = ctx.Quotes
  .Select(q => q.Revisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.RevisionNumber).FirstOrDefault())
  // Do things with the revisions here...
```

The purpose is to get the latest revision of each quote, and then select some information from them.

This works fine, except that we had a rogue quote in the database that didn't have any revisions. Somewhere deep down in the code below what's shown above, I got an exception...

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type

This took an age to debug, as we didn't realise it was caused by the rogue quote. Ideally, the second line of the query would have used First() instead of FirstOrDefault(), which would have thrown an exception right there, showing the source of the problem immediately. However, Entity Framework doesn't allow you to use First() or Single() mid-query, which is why we used FirstOrDefault().

Without rewriting the query completely, ie querying the Revisions table first and navigating back up to the Quote (which would be a pain for other reasons), is there a simple way to guard against this? In this case, I fixed it by changing the first line to...

```
var revisions = ctx.Quotes.Where(q => q.Revisions.Any())
```

...but this is a specific fix for this case, and was only apparent after we eventually found the issue. Ideally, I would like a solution that would be generally applicable.

Comment: The part of the query you show seems fine. Would be interesting to know how it goes on. Suspecting you project the resulting Revision into something that extracts an integer. Please provide the whole query.

Comment: @tinudu As I explained, the part of the query I showed was the problem, as it was assuming that every quote had a revision (which it was supposed to have), and the FirstOrDefault() was returning default, which caused the problem lower down. Didn't matter what was going on further down, I could do nothing, as long as the query had something to enumerate, it threw the exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get an *inner join* semantics, IMO the general replacement of `Select` / `OrderBy` / `FirstOrDefault` is `SelectMany` / `OrderBy` / `Take(1)`:

```
var revisions = ctx.Quotes
    .SelectMany(q => q.Revisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.RevisionNumber).Take(1))
    // Do things with the revisions here...
```

Comment: Brilliaint, such an obvious and simple way of doing it. Makes me wonder why Microsoft felt they couldn't implement First() in EF, when it's the same as Take(1) which they do implement. Thanks for the reply.